# Multiple left joins with a CONCAT returns null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 3 tables in one output, and each table has a unique identifier that *should* join them together. However, in one of my tables, I need to CONCAT 3 columns into a string so it matches the format in another table (Table 1). When I run my sql command, I return null for all columns in the daily weather table which shouldn't be the case.

I get data populating for my first 2 table joins, however dailyweather table returns only null cells.

my sql command is:

```
SELECT results.*,users.cityid,dailyweather.*
FROM results
LEFT JOIN users on results.id = users.id
LEFT JOIN dailyweather ON results.day = CONCAT(dailyweather.day,"-",dailyweather.month,"-",dailyweather.year) WHERE users.cityid = dailyweather.cityid
```

The columns that should match between tables:

1. Results.id = users.id
2. Results.day = CONCAT(dailyweather columns)
3. users.cityid = dailyweather.cityid

**EDIT:** as requested in the comments by @Antique-Rahman and @Claus-Bönnhoff, the format for results.day is tinytext/string and NOT DateTime/Timestamp format

Comment: `so it matches the format in another table` this is just asking or trouble. Normalise your data

Comment: Is results.day datatype DateTime Or Date? You can cast CONCAT(dailyweather.day,"-",dailyweather.month,"-",dailyweather.year) as DateTime.

Comment: We need to know the format of the results.day column. Otherwise we can only guess

Comment: The results.day is tinytext format, not DateTime

Comment: Post sample data of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

*Solution for those interested:*
Normalize your data. I had two tables with dates in a string, and the other table where date items (day/month/year) were separated into unique columns. The column separated dates did not have a zero pad on the front for single digit days whereas the dates did. My solution was to my left join was:

```
results.day =CONCAT_WS("-",LPAD(dailyweather.day, 2, '0'),LPAD(dailyweather.month,2,'0'),dailyweather.year)
```